# Ruby on Rails, how to setup hot swap for lib folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My models are becoming bigger and bigger (fat model thin controller approach) so I am making more and more modules (e.g. /lib/user/*).

Problem is that they don't get re-deployed so each time I have to restart Webrick.

How to set "hot swap" for lib folder?

Thank you, and generally is that good practice since it is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Guard` and `Guard-Rails`. `Guard` allows watching of files/folders and taking actions. `Guard-Rails` will restart your rails server each time a particular file is changed. The default folders for `Guard-Rails` includes the lib folder (and subfolders).

You can find details for [Guard on github](https://github.com/guard/guard).